# How do I Stretch background image in jQuery Mobile CSS to accomidate all screen sizes

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a website that will serve mobile phones and tablets which will have different form factors. I have a background image that I want for the home page and would like that image to stretch (possibly distort) to accommodate the available area.

What is the best way to do this?

Is there a good alternative that would reasonably accommodate vastly different form factors (i.e. Tablet/Phones) that would not distort the image?

===============================

## Update

I leveraged this code.

```
.transparent-background {
    background: transparent;
}

.background-image {
  background: url(app-background.jpg);
  background-repeat:none;
  background-position:center center;
  background-attachment:scroll;
  background-size:100% 100%;    
}
```

I added the transparent-background as a class to the Page and Content elements and then added the background-image class to the page element and that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS3 property background-size:cover;

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

> If the cover keyword is the used, the background image is scaled,
>   again preserving the image’s original proportions / aspect ratio, this
>   time to be as large as possible so that the background positioning
>   area is completely covered by the background image, ie. both the
>   images width or height are equal to or exceed the background
>   positioning area. As such, again depending on whether or not the
>   proportions of the background image match those of the background
>   positioning area, some parts of the background image may not be in
>   view within the background positioning area.

It is not compatible with every browser but should be fine for devices - [Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can do this by just changing/modifying CSS.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Try reading this article more for better understanding.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/

Comment: I don't know if it would work with background-images but with this tag, if you use a sufficiently big image it would scale according to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you can use the @media rule to specify different styles for different screen sizes/devices.  For example:

```
@media all and (min-width: 750px) {

/*Any styles in here will only be applied to browsers(screens, etc) with a width > 750px */

}
```

So you could have different background images/layouts based on screen size by overriding your current styles.  i.e. you may have more high definition images set as the backgrounds of divs, icons, etc for larger screens. If that makes any sense.